# How to change app icon dynamically in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, icons, splash-screen

I'm building Ionic 3 app which will be served for different customers as White label. I have no problem with a dynamic provider of data, styles, etc. but can't guess how to change the main app icon for each customer.

The start screen has 'select' with all customers, after choosing one and press next I upload all data for this particular customer and change my start screen to 'Login' screen for this particular customer (company).

The question is: **how can I change dynamically the main app icon (and splash screen if it's possible ) after the customer chooses his company?**

Thank you.

Comment: you want change at the time of creating apk?

Comment: No, at the time of selecting the customer and relaunch an app on the phone.
Run app --> select customer from select --> Relunch app with new app icon

Comment: Then you cannot change the icon. It is determined in **build**.  But you can change the splash screen via bypass.

Comment: Could you please describe where should I look at least for a dynamic splash screen? Thank you.